# Angular crawlable links inside href For SEO

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I have a list of products in my application and that's displayed as below:

```
In ts
   this.products = [{name:'product one', url:'product-one'},
            {name:'product two', url:'product-two'},
            {name:'product three', url:'product-three'}]

navigateToPage(url){
    this.router.navigate([url]);
}
```

in navigateToPage() function we have some logic so we are not using routerlink
in html

```
 <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let product of products">
    <a (click)="navigateToPage(product.url)">{{product.name}}</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

The links are not crawlable. if i provide like below the site is reloading .

```
<a href="{{product.url}}>{{product.name}}</a>
```

How to make the urls crawlable without reloading the page

Answer (score 0):

You have to use routerLink instead of href

Comment: routerLink i am not able to use because in the function i have to some logic based on that i need to navigate